# pass URL-encoded URL to CURL

Tags: url, curl

How do i pass a URL-encoded URL to CURL?

Ex:

```
curl "http://live.nwk5.net/secure/v.stream/playlist.m3u8?expiry=kFmysuf%2fLjOqgdXGJWqFQA%3d%3d"
```

This returns a invalid page.

if I URL decode the parameter as below, Im getting the expected response. Please Help.

```
curl "http://live.nwk5.net/secure/v.stream/playlist.m3u8?expiry=kFmysuf/LjOqgdXGJWqFQA=="
```

Comment: Why don you use it with the URL decoded parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You're talking in vague terms. curl accepts and expects a URL. You need to provide the correct URL as curl can't guess what you otherwise intended.

If you have the URL encoded into weirdness, you have to first decode it to tell curl the correct URL.

URL-encoding a URL *an extra time* like you seem to have done *partly* (because otherwise you would also have encoded the slashes etc), is what I consider "encoded into weirdness".